# Por qué al autenticar se mantiene en la página de logeo?

Tags: python

Quisiera iniciar sesión en un sitio web, pero al ingresar todos los datos y querer obtener los datos de una se las secciones que sólo se acceden iniciando sesión, éste obtiene los de la página de logeo, y no la del perfil.

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
s.post('site.com/login', auth=('user', 'pass'))
r = s.get('site.com/profile')
print r.content
```

¿Me podrían ayudar indicandome qué estoy haciendo mal? Soy nuevo en python

Comment: Posiblemente no debas usar el parámetro `auth`, sino recuperar (mediante `get`) la página de login para extraer de ahí el formulario que él te envía y poder ver cómo se llaman los campos (es posible que envíe campos ocultos al usuario, pero que serían visibles en el HTML). Entonces prepararás un diccionario con los valores a enviar en cada campo (entre ellos usuario y contraseña) y los enviarás mediante `s.post(url, data=tu_diccionario)`

Comment: @abulafia Eso hice, pero sigue devolviendo el contenido de la página de logueo. :/

Comment: Pues o bien has hecho algo mal (por ejemplo, si el servidor te ha enviado varios campos adicionales además del de usuario y contraseña, debes devolvérselos todos con el valor que hubiera en ellos), o bien el servidor usa algún otro tipo de autenticación no basado en cookies. Pudiera ser que estuviera usando javascript (Ajax) para hacer el envío del formulario, y recibiera a cambio un token JWT, OAuth, o similar, el cual debe ser reenviado con cada petición posterior en la cabecera `Authorization`

Comment: Sin saber detalles de cómo funciona la autenticación en el servidor al que intentas acceder no es posible ayudarte.